# Can't display the color of a table row with angular in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer, html-table

I have this table which I change the color according to the color property value, I'm using ng-repeat for displaying this rows, this is my table

```
<table class="tab table span6 tabhover" style="margin:0;" >
            <thead>
                <th>No. Parte</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Estatus</th>
                <th>Fecha estatus</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="r in reqs">
               <tr ng-class="{selected: r.idrdm_detalles == idSelectedVote}"   ng-click='detallesHistory(r.idrdm_detalles)'    bgcolor="{{r.color}}"> 
                <td>{{r.numeroparte}}</td>
                <td>{{r.cantidad}}</td>
                <td>{{r.descripcion}}</td>
                <td>{{r.estatus}}</td>
                <td>{{r.fecha_estatus}}</td>
               </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

as you can see the bgcolor attribute in the tr tag it's equal to the color property of the object

I'm using this function for setting the color of the row

```
this.color = function(codigo){
            if(codigo == 10){
                return '#00A6E8';
            }
            else if(codigo == 60 || codigo == 80){
                return '#51BD53';
            }
            else if(codigo == 90 || codigo == 99){
                return '#DE5F5F';
            }
            else{
                return '#F5AB2C';
            };
        };
```

and in my controller, I'm using angular foraeach, for adding the color property to my array

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
                    var c = value.codigo;
                    value.color = self.color(c);

                    $scope.idrdm = req; 
                    //console.log(value);
                });
                $scope.reqs = data;
```

The thing is that the table row background color works in every other popular browser such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari but when I use  Internet Explorer the table rows background color is  "#00c00" instead of the one that's supposed to be set, could somebody tell me what it's the approach for this. 
PS. I have used ng-style like this

```
 <tr ng-style="'{background-color':{{r.color}}">
```

and it works, but not on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: I have tried with IE11

Answer (score 0):

I feel like color values belong in CSS, not Javascript. I would do something like this, which may also fix your IE problem. You should use better class names than what I have written, this is just an example.

**JS**

```
this.color = function(codigo){
            if(codigo == 10){
                return 'blue';
            }
            else if(codigo == 60 || codigo == 80){
                return 'green';
            }
            else if(codigo == 90 || codigo == 99){
                return 'red';
            }
            else{
                return 'darkblue';
            };
        };
```

**HTML**

```
 <tr ng-class="'{{r.color}}'">
```

**CSS**

```
.blue {
    background: #00A6E8;
}
.green {
    background: #51BD53;
}
.red {
    background: #DE5F5F;
}
.darkblue {
    background: #F5AB2C;
}
```

Comment: It didnt work man, it works in every other browser but IE, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-style` should be used like this:

```
<tr ng-style="{'background-color': r.color}">
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KmIO5MVXlsBSitTXs19k?p=preview

But if you want to use the `bgcolor`, you could do it with `ng-attr-*` like this:

```
<tr ng-attr-bgcolor="r.color">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you runTarm , it works in every other browser but IE, it's kinda weird

Comment: It doesn't work even open the plunker in IE11 right? It works in my IE10.